# Killed pulseaudio - no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a problem with pavucontrol and I have been told that maybe another program brokeing it.
So I searched how to kill pulseaudio
I did:

```
echo "autospawn = no" > $HOME/.config/pulse/client.conf
pkill -f pulseaudio
```

Now the sound not working, I can't heare songs.
I cleared the conf file and tried to run pulseaudio by

```
pulseaudio --start
```

But nothing happened (just terminal waiting)

now the pulseaudio not running. even from it's icon on menu

What can I do to activate it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the service command for it:

```
sudo service pulseaudio restart
```

If the problem persists:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio -D
```